# Weak convergence function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

I am studying for an exam and this was one of the hard problems in my textbook.

Let $f_n(x) = 1 −\cos(2\pi nx)$ for n $\in$ N and x $\in$  $[0,1]$. Verify that $f_n$ is the density of a probability measure $μ_n$ on $[0,1]$. Is there a weak limit $μ_n\overset{\textrm{weak}}{\longrightarrow}\mu$? Either show convergence and identify $\mu$ or prove that the sequence does not converge. Sketch a graph of $f_n$ and try to give some qualitative justification for your answer.

How should I use weak convergence criteria?